# Dataweave - String array remove square brackets

Tags: arrays, mule, transform, dataweave

I get this **string array**:

`["HELLO","WORLD"]`

And I want to output the same but without square brackets:

`"HELLO","WORLD"`

How can I replace or transform this with **Dataweave** in Mule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions (credit to @jerney in the comments)

Using index manipulation:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java

%var input = "[\"HELLO\", \"WORLD\"]"
---
input[1..-2]
```

Using regex:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java

%var input = "[\"HELLO\", \"WORLD\"]"
---
input replace /^\[|\]$/ with ""
```

Using simple replacement:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java

%var input = "[\"HELLO\", \"WORLD\"]"
---
input replace "[" with "" replace "]" with ""
```

Comment: If you need to be a little bit safer (avoid replacing `[` or `]` for the entire string), `input[1 to -2]` is also an option, assuming `input` is a string.

Comment: Regex is also an option so you don't need to call `replace` twice: `input replace /^\[|\]$/ with ""`, but it seems a little more cryptic.

Comment: I like both of these solutions better, haha. I'll update the answer so they don't get lost in the comments.